# How to disable mouse wheel event in org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo

Tags: eclipse, combobox, mouseevent, mousewheel

I have a combo widget(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo). When I scroll a mouse wheel a value of a  combo box changes. How do I suppress this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Combo myCombo = new Combo(parent, style);
myCombo.addListener(SWT.MouseVerticalWheel, new Listener()
{

  @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            arg0.doit = false;

        }
});
```

Comment: I used SWT.MouseWheel instead of SWT.MouseVerticalWheel because it wasn't available. It works good. Thanks you.